Getting this error in AWS console : code deploy phase 2: Downloadbundle:
Getting this error in AWS console

Code deploy phase 2:  Downloadbundle:  arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:xxx unknown error: The specified key does not exist. View more..........##?

Is the prolem with IAM or s3 or ec2 or code deploy agent?
Here is the appspec file:
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_nginx.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
      #runas for root persmission
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_nginx.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

and the buildspec file:
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing NGINX
      - sudo apt-get update
      - sudo apt-get install nginx -y
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on 'date'
      - cp myprofile.html /var/www/html/
      # cause nginx is a server so file path
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Configuring NGINX

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  # discard-paths: yes

Changed IAM roles of ec2, s3 and code deploy role enabling Ec2forCodedeploy full access and s3 full and ec2 full, attached permissions to ec2 and deployment grp and etc
